# Can Amplify "Web Previews" also provision a temporary database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

### Background

[Web previews](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/pr-previews.html) are an Amplify feature that, on every pull request, auto-deploys the to-be-merged code in its own environment, and creates a URL to the candidate application so reviewers can see it in action.  Quoting AWS's description from the link:

> A web preview deploys every pull request made to your GitHub repository to a unique preview URL which is completely different from the URL your main site uses. For apps with backend environments provisioned using the Amplify CLI, every pull request (private Git repositories only) spins up an ephemeral backend that is deleted when the PR is closed.

### Question

I want to extend the "Web Preview" idea of "fully isolated temporary environment for the new code" to include the database, say a Postgres or Mongo DB that the application uses.

So, on a new PR, we would deploy not only a backend for the candidate code, but also a temporary, fresh copy of our database, pre-filled with known dummy data.  This would help enable consistent, non-flaky end-to-end tests.

1. Does AWS provide a way to do this out of the box?
2. If not, what approach could we use to achieve this?  I assume would it be scriptable somehow, but where would I hook into the Amplify auto-deploy process?

Answer (score 1):

At the link that you posted, you can find the following:

[image]

So, if you select the **Create new backend environment for every Pull Request** option, it will create all BE resources for every pull request created in that repo. However, Amplify's preferred database is DynamoDB, and as of the time of this writing it only supports DynamoDB. If you want to use PostGresQL or MongoDB or another database, I would suggest to [create a custom resource in amplify with AWS CDK](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/custom/cdk/). For pre-populating your newly-created backend resources, you could use an amplify [post-push hook](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/command-hooks/) to execute a script that will copy the data into the tables. Alternatively, you may be able to define initial DB data in the CDK, but I am not certain about this.